# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n\geq1}{z^n \over n}$ over a circular arc

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

As a follow-up to this question [Find all the points which makes the series normal converges and uniformly converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695929/find-all-the-points-which-makes-the-series-normal-converges-and-uniformly-conver/), I'm wondering if the series of function $\sum_{n\geq1}{z^n \over n}$ converges uniformly over circular arcs that don't intersect $1$.

That is to say, given $0<\theta_O<\theta_O'<2\pi$, does this series of functions converge uniformly on the set $\{ e^{i\theta}, \theta \in [\theta_O,\theta_O'] \}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is yes.

Let $S_n(\theta)=\sum_{k=0}^n e^{ik\theta}$.

Note that $$\left|S_n(\theta)\right| =\left|\frac{1-e^{i\theta(n+1)}}{1-e^{i\theta}}\right| \leq \frac 2{|1-e^{i\theta}|}=\frac {\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1-\cos(\theta)}}\leq \max\left(\frac {\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1-\cos(\theta_0)}},\frac {\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1-\cos(\theta_0')}}\right)$$

Let $M=\max\left(\frac {\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1-\cos(\theta_0)}},\frac {\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1-\cos(\theta_0')}}\right)$.

An Abel transform leads to $$\sum_{k=1}^N {e^{ik\theta}\over k}=\sum_{k=1}^N\left(\frac 1k -\frac 1{k+1} \right)S_k(\theta) + \frac{S_N(\theta)}{N+1}-1$$

Hence $$\left| \sum_{k=1}^\infty {e^{ik\theta}\over k} -\sum_{k=1}^N {e^{ik\theta}\over k}\right|= \left| \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \left(\frac 1k -\frac 1{k+1} \right)S_k(\theta) - \frac{S_N(\theta)}{N+1} \right|$$

Then $$\left| \sum_{k=1}^\infty {e^{ik\theta}\over k} -\sum_{k=1}^N {e^{ik\theta}\over k}\right|\leq \frac{2M}{N+1}$$

Hence uniform convergence.